# display different mysql data in a .php document like a cms

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system

Hey this is probably really simple, but i am still a beginner i am a bit confused about that..
I want to create something like a selfmade CMS for my website.

I have a .php document which is querying certain data from my database. Now if i change that data, the document will display the new data. (So i can edit my texts and images..)

My actual question is, how can i create something like a new page. So that i have a form which will write new data into my database and the .php document somehow displays my new data. 
I mean it is the same "template" like my first .php document, but how can i query different things from my database than before?
How does that work in real CMS systems?

Basically i want to write new data in my database with a form. And depending on which url i will click in my index.php, different data is shown in my page1.php document.

I hope you know what i mean. Thank you

EDIT:

To give you an example: A main document with a lot of url's named "data1" "data2" "data3" and so on. If i click on "data2" the showdata.php document should display the data2 which it will find in the database.

Comment: To give answer to your question we need to create an entire application ;-)

Comment: I only want to know the principle behind it

Comment: I have my own CMS and did virtually anything with it but im confused with what you're asking.. pls make it more specific and ill help you

Comment: I don't want to have a .php document which can only display specific data from my database. Instead i want to use the document to display different data, depending on which data the user wants to see. Example: I have a Recipe .php template document. This can display different recipes depending on which url i click on the page before like "cake" or "muffins". I don't want to create a new .php file everytime i add a new recipe into my database. Or it should be created automatically..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the data in the url to write different queries ?

Something like:

```
if (data1) {select data1 from database} elseif(data2){select data2 from database}
```

and so on ? This is what a CMS does actually it, shows different data on the same page based on the url parameters which in php you can use as `$_GET['data1']` or `$_REQUEST['data1']`

Try something like that then update your answer with some code.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. So to use this site as an example, "questions/21881601/display-different-mysql-data-in-a-php-document-like-a-cms" tells this document to search for the question "21881601" in the database and display the data?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the logic.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you're interested in a thing called a CRUD application.

CRUD stands for Create, Read, Update, Delete application.

There are numerous examples of CRUD applications in PHP/MySQL all over the internet.

checkout this link: 
http://thewebmason.com/php-mysql-crud-tutorial-using-pdo-create-read-update-delete-part-1-create/

Comment: That is what i want to be able to do yes. This is simple if i want to edit/write/delete data which is always displayed in a .php document. But i want to have a .php document which displays data depending on what the user wants to see instead of displaying always the same data which can be edited though.

Comment: To give you an example: A main document with a lot of url's named "data1" "data2" "data3" and so on. If i click on "data2" the showdata.php document should display the data2 which it will find in the database

Comment: Than you should make an URL which includes the id of the db entry and on the page that displays the entry fetch the data from the database depending on the db value. see edit action of the CRUD demos and strip the edit form from it. 

Entry (resource) URL should look like http://my.domain.com/show_entry.php?id=1
And in the show_entry.php script you can fetch that id from the $_GET['id'] global variable.